# Struct and Properties update issue

Tags: c#, .net, properties, struct

We use a struct to store data for a project, this struct is Serialized in Xml and then read. The issue is that when we are in the Read method of the struct, we put the correct values in the properties, but when we are in the class that own the struct, we still have the default value.

```
public struct Duration : IXmlSerializable
{
    private const string XML_VALUE = "Value";
    private const string XML_UNIT = "Unit";

    public float Value { get; set; }
    public DurationUnit Unit { get; set; }//DurationUnit is an enum

    public Duration(float value, DurationUnit unit): this()
    {
        Value = value;
        Unit = unit;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        Value = reader.GetAttribute<float>(XML_VALUE);
        Unit = reader.GetAttribute<DurationUnit>(XML_UNIT);
        //Here in debugger, the properties are correctly initialized we the value in the XML
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString(XML_VALUE, Value);
        writer.WriteAttributeString(XML_UNIT, Unit);
        //After we wrote the file, it contains the correct values in the XML
    }
}

public class MyOtherClass():IXmlSerializable{

    public Duration SelectedDuration { get; set; }

    public MyOtherClass(){
        SelectedDuration = new Duration();
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        //we read the xml, we check the reader.Name to see what we do
        if(the_current_node_is_the_duration_to_read){
            using (XmlReader subReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
            {
                SelectedDuration.ReadXml(subReader);
                //And here, after we were having the correct values into the SelectedDuration.ReadXml, we have the wrong(default) values
                //Why?
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Why? We didn't gave the Duration in parameter of a method? I'm aware of the "We should not have a "mutable struct", but in this case, I don't understand what could hurts(or why?)

Comment: This code doesn't compile: `public class MyOtherClass()`

Comment: Matthew's answer is correct, I'd just like to add that unless you know what you are doing simply stay away from structs. They are mostly useful for dealing with things like mathematical values (numbers, vectors, quaternions, ...) and similar things like Colors (basically a vector with 4 components).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Duration` is a struct, it is a *value type*.

Therefore the getter defined in `public Duration SelectedDuration { get; set; }` will return a COPY of the struct, and any changes you make to it will be made to the copy, NOT to the original one.

Two possible solutions:

1. Make it a class instead.
2. Assign back the result of calling `ReadXml()` like so:

   SelectedDuration = SelectedDuration.ReadXml(subReader);

You could also write a new `UpdateSelectedDurationFromXml()` method to use instead:

```
public void UpdateSelectedDurationFromXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    Duration duration = new Duration();
    duration.ReadXml(reader);
    SelectedDuration = duration;
}
```

Comment: In other words, structs are copied bit-by-bit when being passed into a method or returned from a method. Since the property getter is compiled to a method that returns the struct (`get_SelectedDuration()`), the struct will be copied. If this was a field, then it wouldn't be copied.

Comment: I'm well aware of the value type thing, I just didn't thought that a property was considered as a "method" that give a new value. So the issue is not directly IN my struct but in the class that contains it. If I create a backing Field for "SelectedDuration" and use this backing field in my ReadXml, will it works?

Comment: @J4N Exactly. But that's bad design IMO. Is there a reason why you're not using a reference type instead?

Comment: @J4N Yes, if you use a backing field directly it will work because you aren't then working with a struct returned from a method. Also note that properties are implemented as methods.

Comment: We may have a lot of them in memory, and struct are lighter. I'm not a big fan of `struct` either but it has as much reason to be a struct that `DateTime` has ;)

Comment: @J4N Have you measured the app's performance with structs vs with classes? Also, why does it have to be mutable?

Comment: @dcastro No we didn't, and due to our application size, I don't expect to see a noticeable change without doing a custom application test. How to implement IXmlSerializable without being mutable?

Answer (score 0):

C# does a few evil things with structures.  The later part of your code is equivalent to:

```
        using (XmlReader subReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
        {
            var temp = SelectedDuration;
            temp.ReadXml(subReader);
        }
```

I think it's pretty clear given the above code why `SelectedDuration` isn't getting modified by the `ReadXML` call--because that call is modifying `temp`.

Because of that, one should avoid having struct instance methods which modify the underlying structure, and instead use static methods that accept the struct to be modified as a `ref` parameter.  If the `ReadXml` method were written as:

```
public static void ReadXml(ref Duration it, XmlReader reader)
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    it.Value = reader.GetAttribute<float>(XML_VALUE);
    it.Unit = reader.GetAttribute<DurationUnit>(XML_UNIT);
}
```

and the call were written as

```
Duration.ReadXml(ref SelectedDuration, subReader);
```

then rather than copy the property to a variable and invoking the method on that, the compiler would squawk that properties cannot be passed as `ref` parameters.  This problem could then be fixed by either rewriting the calling code as:

```
var temp = SelectedDuration;
Duration.ReadXml(ref SelectedDuration, subReader);
SelectedDuration = temp;
```

or else by making `SelectedDuration` a field rather than a property.

Note that using a static method and passing the thing to be modified as a `ref` parameter won't make the code work, but it will prevent the compiler from silently changing code which won't compile into code which will compile but can't possibly work.